# Counting That's as two words in c

Tags: c, counting, words, apostrophe

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long c;
    unsigned long line;
    unsigned long word;
    char ch;

    c = 0;
    line = 0;
    word = 0;

    printf("Please enter text:\n");
    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        c ++;
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
        line ++;
        }
        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n')
        {
        word ++;
        }
    }
    printf( "%lu %lu %lu\n", c, word, line );
    return 0;
}
```

Right now my program works and it counts correctly for characters, words, and lines.  But for words like That's, the program counts it as 1 word and I want it to count as 2 words.  What would I need to add to account for that?

Comment: What about "it's" and "let's" and "Jim's"?

Comment: What word count does your program give for an input that has several consecutive spaces, and is that correct for your purposes?

Comment: So, "How do I detect and count a *contraction* as two words in a word-count algorithm?" would sum up your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(ch =='\'' || ch == ' ' || ch == '\n')
{
    word++;
}
```

Comment: Assuming he only wants conjunctions to be counted as two words, "Party at Jim's" would return an incorrect word count.